# Static webpage webpack hotloader does not work

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-html-loader

Here is a repo I just created to get this issue solved: https://github.com/DevCubeHD/WebpackStaticPage

First of all: File structure. There are two important folders you should know to understand my example in case it isn't even convention. The `/src` folder is where all the raw content goes and the `/dist` folder is where the packed website goes by default. From there it is ready to deploy on any server. I'm not sure if development needs this directory anyways, but I hope you are.

I'm trying to set-up two webpack scripts for production and development.
Production works fine: The script runs trough and the page is put into `/dist`.

In development I want to use webkit hotloader to instantly apply changes to the page just when I made some. It does run and the output seems very good, but when it comes to the page it stucks on `[WDS] App hot update...` and does not update the content. Even after a refresh of the page the content is still the old. The only thing that helps is running the production script.

To run the development script use `yarn start` or `npm run start`. For a fresh `/dist` directory you can use the production script `yarn build` or `npm run build` at the moment.

Please help me to fix the webback-dev-server so I can develop efficently. :) Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` from `webpack`.

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
]
```

[Hot Module Replacement Plugin Link](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/hot-module-replacement-plugin/)

Comment: Does not change anything since --hot and --inline is added to the yarn start script

Comment: Have my repo for reference, i did the same and it is working for me. I started dev-server with just `webpack-dev-server` no `--hot` or `--inline`, as those are already configured in webpack config.

Comment: my react app works either, but not my static webpage

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this by doing the following things,

1. Remove `main.js` and `main.less` from webpack entry points and only have `index.html`
2. Add `HotModuleReplacementPlugin`
3. Remove `assets` folder and putting all files in a single folder.

Comment: I will try have a short wait

Comment: wait how should that even work? less and js wouldn't be in the the path

Comment: I tried adding less file directly in the "link:href" and add it to the html loader, but for any reason it cannot handle them and throws an error like undefined.toString() is not a function

Comment: include `main.js` and `main.less` in `index.html`

Comment: I added attrs: ['img:src', 'link:href', 'script:src'] to the html-loader config and set <link href="src/less/main.less" rel="stylesheet"> and the same with js.. but im ending up with this error https://hastebin.com/odaweqogik.coffeescript

Comment: `attrs` not required, only those `<link>` `<script>` tags are enough with file path

Comment: well, how should the files be detected then? If the html-loader does not recognize them - nobody will, or am I wrong?

Comment: Please be so kind and clone the repo to try it yourself - I almost tried everything myself - aaaand guessing is not the way we can solve this together

Comment: okay, i already cloned the repo and worked on it, i will raise a pull request with those changes